# how to scale all the compositions in a after effects project?

Tags: video, adobe, after-effects, visual-effects

I have a after effects template whose preset is 1920*1080 , but I need the output to be in 20 * 8 sq feet. How can I change the whole project composition settings to fit the screen ?
 I tried to scale the project by using "File -> scripts -> scale composition .jsx" but I change the width, then the height changes simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

There is not automatic way to scale a composition without constrained proportions, but the right way to do it would be to:

1. Parent your layers to a null layer;
2. Open composition settings and set the desired width and height;
3. Scale the null layer accordingly;
4. (Optional) Delete the null layer.